# Is there a difference between the particle お (o) and the particle を (wo)

Tags: grammar, particles

So I'm just confused. I've read that when writing **を** is used, but when talking **お** is used. Is this true or are they entirely different?

Comment: Yes, を is pronounced the same as お when speaking. There is no particle お.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but if you had just searched "the particle お (o) and the particle を (wo)" in a search engine, you would have found that there is no お particle pretty quick.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to distinguish **spelling** and **pronunciation**.  You do this all the time in English: you're aware that ***two*** ("one plus one") and ***too*** ("also") have the same pronunciation even though they're spelled differently.

Likewise, in Japanese, keep in mind that **the particle を is always spelled を**, even though its basic pronunciation is the same as お.

---

を and お used to be distinguished in pronunciation, but they merged  about a thousand years ago.  The distinction was retained in spelling for a long time after, just like how in English we still write ***knight*** even though no one pronounces the ***k*** or ***gh*** anymore.

But the distinction in spelling didn't last forever.  After World War 2, Japanese spelling was finally revised and every word with を was re-spelled with お instead.  をとこ became おとこ, and so on.

#### Every word except one!  The particle を.

For some reason, the spelling reformers decided to keep the particles は, へ, and を rather than re-spell them わ, え, and お.  You'll just have to memorize this.  There are some other ways Japanese spelling is different from pronunciation, for example in long vowels:

```
  王　　（おう）　king 　　　(pronounced like オー)
  追う　（おう）　chase　　　(pronounced like オウ)
```

You'll have to keep the differences between spelling and pronunciation in mind as you learn Japanese.

---

Although every Japanese dialect has lost the distinction between を and お, there are some people who pronounce を as /wo/ today as a spelling pronunciation.  You'll also hear a /w/ inserted in some phonetic contexts such as after ん /N/, but this insertion isn't phonemic—that is, it isn't used to distinguish を from お.  Likewise, you'll often hear を as /wo/ in songs, but you'll also hear singers insert /w/ before お, so you can't rely on the presence of /w/ to distinguish お and を in modern Japanese, even in songs.

Regardless of any phonetic variation, **the particle を is always spelled を**.